# iPhone Team Provisioning Profile - Invalid

Tags: iphone, provisioning

On the iPhone Provisioning Portal, it shows my iPhone Team Provisioning Profile is Invalid. There is a "Managed by Xcode" text. The "renew" button is disabled.

How can I fix that? Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using Xcode 3.2.4, open the organiser window and navigate to the Team Provisioning profile in the profiles section to the left. At the top of the window you should see a refresh button next to the "Automatic provisioning" checkbox. Clicking that should prompt you for your developer credentials and recreate the profile for you

**EDIT:** You can also right click the device in organiser once it's connected to your machine and manually request that it be added via the context menu

Comment: When I click Refresh in Organizer, I get the following error: "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again.  If the problem persists, please contact Apple Developer Support.
http://developer.apple.com/support"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939049/iphone-renew-team-provisioning-profile

Comment: I get the same error as Rei, but on the Provisioning Portal the profile now shows as Active. If I then re-download the Team profile and delete the old one, it works.

Answer (score 10):

If you have invalid Distribution Provisioning Profiles in your App developer account, the easiest way to renew the profiles is “modify” → then just change something and press submit.

You dont have to re-create neither the appstore or adhoc profile and can just renew them this way.

Answer (score 1):

All the times I tried to fix stuff regarding the provisioning didn't help, I always end up doing the original process again.

So I recommend you do the same instead of trying to understand the spaghetti interface.

Answer (score 1):

This happened with xcode 5.1.1
To activate the provisioning profile again do this:

- go to xcode preferences
- Select team
- View details
- Refresh Provisioning Profiles

After the last step, the provisioning profile becomes active.

Answer (score 1):

In modern versions of xcode 5 or greater

1. select accounts

[image]

2. Select your dev account and View Details...

[image]

3. Hit the refresh button and now if you look in your ios provisioning profiles at developer.apple.com they should be green

[image]

Comment: can't even begin to tell you how much I want to love you. I'm homeless but I have a few washcloths and newspapers we can cuddle under

Answer (score 0):

same problem, same solution. 
Gave me the same error ("An unexpected error occurred"), but then the "renew" button on the provisiioning portal is enabled (or better, it becomes "Download"). Simply download it and double click it and you're done

Answer (score -2):

Leave that profile alone: It's managed by Xcode.

Create another profile.

Comment: It's managed by Xcode, but not properly. It expires and Xcode doesn't automatically renew it. Hence the question.

Comment: Right. But you NEVER touch it in this UI.