# iPhone -- renew team provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, provisioning

In the provisioning portal, the "renew" button for my team provisioning profile is grayed out.  And said profile is expired.

How can I renew it?

EDIT: I found the "automatic device provisioning" checkbox and "refresh" button in the organizer in Xcode.  But when I select the team profile, check the checkbox, and push the refresh button, I get this message:

*An unexpected error occurred. Please try again.  If the problem persists, please contact Apple Developer Support (http://developer.apple.com/support).*

I suppose I can go to support, but it would still be better to figure out what the problem is without involving them.

Comment: I see someone voted to close this.  I just want to say that per the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) I think it is relevant as a "matter that is unique to the programming profession."

Comment: Not sure about your "unexpected error", but I used the automatic...refresh option and it did me just fine, so +1 for the Q&A.  NOTE: I had to renew my actual developer certificate (which had also expired) first.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had the same "unexpected error" issue with the Team Provisioning Profile when it expired. I fixed it by deleting it in the Xcode Organizer AND in the ADC Provisioning Portal, then hitting renew in Organizer.

Comment: Thanks.  I had been deleting it in just Xcode.  That didn't do the trick.  But when I also deleted it in the Portal, presto!

Comment: Ran into this tonight like others.  I had the disabled Renew button in the Provisioning Portal, etc.  I was able to just delete it from Xcode Organizer, then Refresh in Xcode, and that re-downloaded it and renewed it.  I never had to delete it from the Portal, so YMMV.

Comment: In organizer delete the "team" profile from your devices and your "profiles" tabs... then in the developer portal delete it also... now unplug your phone and reconnect your phone, it should automatically reformat the organizer to have the proper connections this time... now right click on the device and select "add device to provisioning portal", finally go to your project files build settings and change the distribution signing settings to the new corresponding team profile.

Answer (score 6):

Posting this again here..

OK, I had the same problem with the disabled 'Renew' button against my Team Provisioning Profile.

This worked for me.

1) Deleted the expired Team Provisioning Profile from the Xcode Organizer.

2) Deleted the same thing from the developer provisioning portal.

3) Again from Xcode organizer check marked the auto provision and clicked 'Refresh'. it asked for the credentials and in a few seconds added the renewed Team Provisioning Profile.

4) It also added the new profile in the developer provisioning portal.

Answer (score 6):

Refresh and removing the iOS devices did not help on my installation.

But I found that the error messages was misleading. I am also member of the Mac developer program and after choosing "My Mac" under DEVICES and pressing the (+) Add to Portal button, the error message "Your team has no devices for which to generate a provisioning profile." did no longer appear.

So it looks like the error message covers the Mac and not iOS devices even that the URL at the end of the error message links to the iOS development center.

Answer (score 3):

I had the issue that Xcode didn't refresh or renew it's managed Team Provisioning Profile and tried a very long time. I always hit refresh in the Library->Provisioning Profiles - section. Then I tried out the Teams section and after hitting the refrsh button there my Team Provisioning Profile which was managed by Xcode was renewed successfully. Hope this helps some of you.

One more thing: I used the same Apple-ID in three teams. So maybe Xcode failed to separate them while refreshing.

Answer (score 2):

Do these things if you want to really solve the problem:

(1) Are you using the certificate for which you made provisional profile from your mac? Or you are using the certificate from other mac machine. If that is the thing then please get .p12 file from there and install in your keychain.

(2) If your certificate in the keychain is the same for which you made the provisional profile then it's fine. Otherwise you have to create new provisional profile for the certificate.

(3) Please make sure that you have set the app id in the target > properties > identifier. If no then please set and choose the provisional profile from the target > build > code signing identity.

(4) Then clean and build your project.

If you find any problem then please let me know. I would like to solve this problem.

Comment: My certificate was indeed from other machine, that was why I was getting this problem after I had renewed the subscription with Apple. I did what AppAspect suggested i.e. went to other machine and generated .p12 in keychain for all my certificates and opened it on the other machine, they got installed and that was it, I was able to build onto iPhone again.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by signing into my **Apple ID** in `XCode->Preferences->Accounts` tab

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is the certificate it is based on expired?  Did you delete the device it was for?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the profile and click Refresh so Xcode re-adds it. Just a guess. I don't know why this would work, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Are you pressing the renew button from within Organizer in the latest Xcode version, 3.2.5 beta 3?

Comment: Have now tried it.  Same problem.  Additionally, my device doesn't have iOS4.2 (would that even be possible yet?) -- but it doesn't get that far.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to compiling question, however, if anyone else has the answer to the team provisioning profile please post.

You can still compile apps for your device/simulator by creating a developer profile and downloading it to your device.

The key to getting it to work is to make sure the profile is selected in both the Edit Project and Edit Target Settings from the Project Menu. The Target Setting is more specific and usually screws people up. Making sure they are both in sync will help you get things up and running.

From these two menus, check the Build tab and make sure the developer profile is displayed. The default is iPhone Developer and should point to your downloaded profile.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem using a different mobileprovision file? I believe you are getting the error on using a different provision file because your Target might be using the older one.

Try this

- Get the new mobileprovision file and
  in Project's Build properties, set
  the mobileprovision to this one
- Select the active target and in the
  target's Build properties, ensure
  that the same mobileprovision is
  being used
- Compile the app.

See if that helps.

Comment: Ok once again, what is the app id you have used for your mobileprovision file (in the Developer portal) and is it the same as the Bundle Identifier in your plist while trying to sign the app with this mobileprovision?

Answer (score 0):

**As far as the Team Provisioning profile goes:**

Does your console say anything? Are you using Xcode 3.2.5? I'd file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com.  Do you see the Team Provisioning file in the iOS Provisioning Portal?  Does it have a green light?

You might try revoking it and letting Xcode create a new one.

**As far as getting your app to work**

You can always create an app-specific development profile.  Choose your certificate and the app you are working on.  Also make sure to select your device in the checkbox list.

Then download the profile (once it is ready) and double click on it to import it into Xcode.

If you look at the Xcode organizer, you should see your development profile in the list.

- If it's red, that means your certificate has expired
- If it's yellow, that means you don't have the private key present to sign using the selected certificate

In the project's Get Info window, under code signing, choose iPhone Developer for both pickers.  Take a look at see which one is automatically selected (sometimes you have to manually choose the right one).

Then do a Clean & Build and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I made the mistake of looking in Wrong place in Organizer.

On the left is LIBRARY then below that DEVICES

I had clicked on my Iphone under DEVICES > Prov profile. 
No refresh button there.

Correct place is

On the left in ORGANIZER is Library > Provisioning Profiles

then Team provision Profile is here

Click on it and hit refresh if expired

Answer (score 0):

As always.... "grep -ir profile ." and the cmd line are always your best friend when you want to fix an Apple frustrating, inconvenience and pain in the ass.... Spent almost an hour poking around xcode trying to find that option to enter the new provisioning profile number, and none to be found... Only when I grep'd for it, was I able to fix, yet another apple pain in the ass.... I can't tell you how many times I've spend hours going through xcode, stuck, because it won't compile because of some stupid invalid setting, profile or argument, only to fix it when I fell back on grep & ssed...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. start xcode.
2. Window->Organizer from menu
3. Choose "Provisioning Profiles" from DEVELOPMENT menu.
4. click refresh button
5. exit organizer
6. return to xcode main window.
7. Build->Clean from menu
8. build and run.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by going to the portal and clicking "modify" on all expired profiles. Then click "select all" for devices and submit.