# App profile needs to be renewed?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I just clicked on Organiser in XCode (I'm running latest publicly available version), and I noticed on one of my apps profiles it says "renew" so I click on that and I get an error msg, saying..

> The given profile was not found on the provisioning portal.
>
> Please refresh your provisioning profiles before attempting to renew
>   “AppProfile"

I don't understand any of that. So...

1) What is it asking me to renew? a development profile? do I need to renew developer profiles? what happens if I don't?

2) Why am I getting an error? what does it mean by "refresh my provisioning profiles" ?

3) Do I have to do this (whatever this is and however I have to fix it) for all profiles? development and distribution?

Comment: For starters here is [the link to iOS provisioning portal info](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/ProvisioningPortal_Recipes/AddingaDeviceIDtoYourDevelopmentTeam/AddingaDeviceIDtoYourDevelopmentTeam.html)

Comment: Secondly, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939049/iphone-renew-team-provisioning-profile) is another SO question that might lead you in the right direction.

Comment: just answered your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i dont know if you have found an answer or not but here is my answer.

- you need a valid developer and also distribution profile ( i am sure you are aware of this already) to upload your app. if your app is uploaded and is in the app store you still have maintain a valid developer profile in order for your app to stay in the app store. otherwise they will bring it down.
- the fact that it asks you to refresh your developer profile is related to the new system of developer profiles that all of a sudden got introduced. there is no need of renewing your profiles every 3 months anymore. your profiles are good for a year. you have to go to organizer in xcode and select all the profiles you have in there. delete them and then go to your team or your own name on the right pane and there you find the refresh button down at the bottom of the window. when you use that it resyncs your profiles with the developer site.
- yes you may have to do that for all of your profiles if you have not done that in past three months.

i hope you find my answer useful.

Edit:

Just go to the developers site and revoke the ones that are about to expire or already expired. Then remove them from keychain and xcode also. Then in keychain create a new certificate request and on the Dev site create new profiles. After creating the new ones download them so they can synch with keychain. After that go the organizer and refresh. Xcode will synch with developer site and will download the new ones. Make sure you connect your test devices so the new profiles can be updated as well. That should do the trick.

Comment: I deleted the profile that said it needed to be renewed. Then went to the team panel and hit refresh. Went back to the profiles, and the deleted profile had reappeared, but now it says it will run out on the 6th of April, not long from now??

Comment: The profile used was for a game that I used Adobe AIR to create the .ipa with, does that make any difference? or it's just about creating the new certs/profiles only?

Comment: No it's just about the cents and has nothing to do with your game. As long as our Dev cents are in order the games and other apps in App Store should be just fine.

Comment: I revoked all the development certs on the dev portal, deleted them all in XCode organiser, but couldnt' see where to delete anything in the keychain, and then went to organiser in XCode and hit refresh.
XCode seemed to sync and download everything again, but the old profiles are still there with the same expiration dates on them, but it's also added a new one called "ios team provisioning profile:myAppsName" which has a 2014 expiration date. So not sure what's going on, can I do the same for the distribution profiles? I get a warning when I try to do that.

Comment: Yes you can do the same thing to your distribution cert too. If you don't delete the old certs from your key chain they will keep popping up in xcode and they will give you some trouble in the future when you want to archive another binary. For now it seems that this way you are able to resolve the issue you are having problem with. Just go ahead and do the same thing with your distribution certificate and you should be good to go.

Comment: How do I find them in the keychain though? I just see a distribution and developer cert and that's it.

Comment: your distribution and developer profile both should be in key chain. unless you are part of the developer team and someone else has the right to be administrator and he is the one who is distributing the app through app store. you should see the distribution profile in the key chain along side your developer profile.

Comment: Oh right, I thought you meant I would see a profile for the actual app in the profile? but you mean there would just be the dev and distribution profile? and I can delete them and recreate them in the dev portal and put them back in again? So the dev and distribution profiles contain all the certs for my current apps?

Comment: Yes that is exactly the case.

Comment: Are there any bad things that can happen from deleting things from the keychain? I'm sure I read somewhere about you have to be careful and people having issues with doing that?

Comment: Yes. You can only remove the profiles that are related to your developers cert. don't delete anything else. Off course if by accident you remove something, you can always downloaded it from apple site.

Comment: Sorry for keeping asking to be clear! :) but when you say "related to your developers cert" you are including in that the distribution profile as well? those 2 profiles, the development and distribution ones and all the associated certs of those?

Comment: That is the only 2. Do not remove any other cert. most of the other ones are related to the programs in your Mac. Such iTunes and a bunch of other programs. Leave them be. Just deal with developer and distribution.

Comment: Deleting all of them has no effect. Problem remains :(